# Textbox value null when trying to access it

Tags: asp.net

```
namespace Dynamic_Controls.Dropdowndynamic
{
public partial class DropdowndynamicUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ControlCount != 0)
        {
            Recreatecontrols();
        }
    }

    private void Recreatecontrols()
    {
       // createtextboxes(ControlCount);
        createtextboxes(2);
    }

    protected void createtextboxes(int ControlCount)
    {
        DynPanel.Visible = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <= ControlCount; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Width = 150;
            tb.Height = 18;
            tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
            tb.ID = "TextBoxID" + this.DynPanel.Controls.Count;
            tb.Text = "EnterTitle" + this.DynPanel.Controls.Count;
            tb.Load+=new EventHandler(tb_Load);
            tb.Visible = true;
            tb.EnableViewState = true;
            DynPanel.Controls.Add(tb);
            DynPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

        }

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 newControlCount = Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        //createtextboxes(newControlCount);
        //ControlCount+=newControlCount;
        createtextboxes(2);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        readtextboxes();

    }

    public void readtextboxes()
    {
        string x = string.Empty;
        for (int a = 0; a < DynPanel.Controls.Count; a++)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in DynPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    x = ((TextBox)ctrl).Text;
                }
                x+=x+("\n");
            }

            Result.Text = x;
        }
    }

    private Int32 ControlCount
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["ControlCount"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["ControlCount"] = 0;

            }
            return (Int32)ViewState["ControlCount"];
        }
        set
        {
           // ViewState["ControlCount"] = value;
            ViewState["ControlCount"] = 2;
        }
    }


    private void tb_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblInfo.Text = ((TextBox)sender).ID + "entered"; 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding these controls dynamically in `Page_Load` (by, I'm assuming, calling your `AddRequiredControl()` method)?  If so, is it wrapped in a conditional which checks for `IsPostBack`?  The likely culprit is that you're destructively re-populating the page with controls before you get to the button click handler, so all the controls would be present but empty (as in an initial load of the page).

Also, just a note, if you're storing each control in `_txt` in your loop, why not refer to that variable instead of re-casting on each line.  The code in your loop seems to be doing a lot of work for little return.

Comment: I am not calling the method AddRequiredControl() on PageLoad , first time it is getting called only on DropdownListSelection Changed. Please help me accessing teh value of each textbox that are loaded

Comment: @Janet: I just noticed something that should have been obvious to me earlier... How about where that method is called in the button click handler?  When you click a button, the first thing you do is re-populate all of the controls.  Then immediately afterward you get their values.  Well, they were just created.  So their values will be empty.  Why are you re-populating the controls on the button click?  Also, why does your method have arguments but the calls to it do not?  What are you actually calling?

Comment: David, I have posted almost all the code, could you guide me pls, in retrieving the values entered by the users in the textboxes

Comment: @Janet: Yes, you've posted a _lot_ of code.  And I'm fairly certain it's not all relevant.  One thing you're going to want to do, just as a basic debugging practice, is to try to re-create the problem using the minimum amount of code possible.  This is a big step toward revealing what's causing the problem.  As it stands now, I'm not going to try to re-create this myself and step through it in a debugger myself.  Honestly, you can do that.  Either way, I'm still suspicious of how you call `CreateRequiredDynamicControls()` just before accessing the dynamic controls in the click event.

Comment: I pasted the whole code, just to show how the createRequiredDynamicControls has two other methods in them and how the controls are being generated. I tried not to call CreateRequiredDynamicControls method in additem click event, but if I dont do that the controls are no longer there on the page.I tried to use the pseodo code pasted above however it did not work may be i am missing something.

Comment: @Janet: Honestly, what you're missing is a debugger.  You have a lot of code here, and it's a bit of a mess, and a lot of things can be going wrong with it.  You should attempt to re-create the problem with as little code as possible.  Separate out the various concerns on the page.  Creating dynamic controls (just use two manually-created ones to test, rather than all of that XML parsing), a single post-back event, checking those controls on the post-back.  Trim out all of the unrelated code and you're more likely to find the problem.

Comment: @David I have pasted that is almost is the functionality that I want to achieve, however i dont get it my code,

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate any dynamically created controls *on or before* Page_Load or they won't contain postback data.

I'm not entirely clear what happens on `DropdownList` changed - are you trying to preserve anything that has been entered already based on the textboxes previously generated?

In any event (no pun intended) you need to recreate exactly the same textboxes in or before `Page_Load` that were there present on the postback, or there won't be data.

A typical way to do this is save something in `ViewState` that your code can use to figure out what to recreate - e.g. the *previous* value of the `DropDownList`. Override `LoadViewState` and call the creation code there in order to capture the needed value, create the textboxes, then in the `DropDownList` change event, remove any controls that may have been created in `LoadViewState` (after of course dealing with their data) and recreate them based on the new value.

*edit* - i can't figure out how your code works now, you have `AddRequiredControl` with parameters but you call it with none. Let's assume you have a function `AddRequiredControls` that creates all textboxes for a given `DropDownList1` value, and has this signature:

`void AddRequiredControls(int index)`

Let's also assume you have a `PlaceHolder` called `ControlsPlaceholder` that will contain the textboxes. Here's some pseudocode:

```
override void LoadViewState(..) {
    base.LoadViewState(..);
    if (ViewState["oldDropDownIndex"]!=null) {
        AddRequiredControls((int)ViewState["oldDropDownIndex"]);
    }
}

override OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
{
    // process data from textboxes    
}

void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(..) {
    ControlsPlaceholder.Controls.Clear();
    AddRequiredControls(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
    ViewState["oldDropDownIndex"]=DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: I have pasted almost 80% of my code. Please check it and let me know the above approach what you have mentioned would be correct. Please hlp as I need to submit this tomororw.very urgent

Comment: All you should need to do is change `CreateRequiredDynamicControls` to accept as parameters the data that determines which controls get created, looks like `ddlChargeCategory` and `ddlChargeCode`, and store those in viewstate as I've shown above whenever they change, and then call that function with the values from viewstate as in the example. THen clear the controls and call it again with the current values when something changes.

Comment: then the method OnLoad will get me the user entered values from textboxes is it?

Comment: As long as the textboxes have been recreated before OnLoad, the same as they were at postback, yes.

Comment: protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState) { base.LoadViewState(savedState); if ViewState["olddropdownindex"]!=null) { CreateRequiredDynamicControls((int)ViewState["olddropdownindex"]); } } If I do this it throws an error No overload for method CreateRequiredDynamicControls takes 1 arguments because that methods has no arguments

Comment: There are two other methods which are defined in CreateRequiredDynamicControls public void AddHeaderControls & public void AddRequiredControl

Comment: I'm trying to explain how to deal with this problem. I can't write your code for you. If you aren't sure what the error about "mo overload method" means then you need some more fundamental assistance.

Comment: string ctrlStr = String.Empty; foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form) { if (ctl.Contains("something")) { ctrlStr = ctl.ToString();something.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form[ctrlStr]);   I finally got it .....Yeah